# Dynamically Add remove rows with custom lookup in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have to add row dynamically and i have to use Custom lookup comp in  first column.On the basis of lookup other fields values will be rendered in first row.
But I am not able to add new row with blank values.
I have followed blogs related to dynamically add/remove rows but nothing is helpfull in my case.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to conditionally render rows in iteration lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235223/how-to-conditionally-render-rows-in-iteration-lightning-component)

Comment: Thanks @AtlasCan ..for quick response.But this is not applicable to my scenario as i am trying to new row after selecting the custom lookup value.  and i am not getting new row with same data that i have filled in previous row.